# Problem with GPS module and Python

Tags: python, gps

I copied a program from the Adafruit webpage to test my GPS module and before running it I installed the Python `gps` with `sudo apt-get install python-gps` but when I run the program I get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python gps.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps.py", line 1, in <module>
    import gps
  File "/home/pi/gps.py", line 4, in <module>
    session = gps.gps("localhost", "2947")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am new with Python so I don't know what is going wrong. I think the program can't find the library but I don't know why and how fix it.

Info:

- I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 running Jessie
- The GPS module is a Ublox NEO 6m

Comment: Could you include how you installed the Python module?

Answer (score 0):

I feel so noob. 
The problem was that I had named the file as gps.py. So it can't import the gps library. Now is working.

Comment: Please accept your answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again after years.